# saving appended list/dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I am working on a code like below, which slices the address column. For this I have created a dictionary and created an empty list `final` to append all the pre processing.see code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA"]

df_dict = df.to_dict('records')

final = []
for row in df_dict:
    add = row["address"]
    # print(add.split("\\n") , len(add.split("\\n")))
    if len(add.split("\\n")) > 3:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = target[-3:]
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    else:
        target = add.split("\\n")
        target = '\\n'.join(target)
    final.append(target)
    print(target)
```

After preprocessing I am appending the empty list. Now, I want to update the `df_dict` with the `final` list. and convert the `df_dict` to pandas dataframe.

sample out put:

```
id  address
1   290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA
2   1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA
3   145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to convert your list with `df = pd.DataFrame (list, columns = ['address'])` ?

Comment: yes but dataframe is different and final list is different I wanted to retain id column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can operate directly on your df using `str.split` and `apply` to re-join the last 3 segments:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':  [1, 2, 3],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id')
df['address'] = df['address'].str.rsplit('\\n', n=3).apply(lambda x: '\\n'.join(x[-3:]))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                           address
id
1            290 Valley Dr.\nCasper, WY 82604\nUSA
2   1180 Shelard Tower\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\nUSA
3             145 S. Durbin\nCasper, WY 82601\nUSA
```

Edit: converting your df to a dict and back is a waste of resource. You can implement your calculations in a functions and use `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id')

def many_calculations(row):
    row['address'] = "\\n".join(row['address'].rsplit('\\n', 3)[-3:])
    # add further calculations for your row here
    return row

df = df.apply(many_calculations, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi Trambi, I am also doing many analysis. SO I need to append the ```final``` to dataframe or df_dict. SO I can't use this because I am also doing many calculations. What I provided here is a simplified version

Comment: You might want to use apply with a more complex function then? Please update your question with working code.

Comment: I have edited to make  you understand

Comment: @SushmithaKrishnan I edited my answer. Don't convert to dict then back to df. It's far easier and much more efficient to process your df directly

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```py
data = {'id':  ['001', '002', '003'],
        'address': ["William J. Clare\\n290 Valley Dr.\\nCasper, WY 82604\\nUSA",
                    "1180 Shelard Tower\\nMinneapolis, MN 55426\\nUSA",
                    "William N. Barnard\\n145 S. Durbin\\nCasper, WY 82601\\nUSA"]
       }

data= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thats the original data from which I doing manupilation

Comment: @SushmithaKrishnan I'm sorry but i don't really get what you actually wanted to do

Comment: I have edited to make you understand